# Graphic Design software with Variable Font support

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation

Which **Graphic Design software** have you found to work well with **Variable Fonts**?

How are you making use of Variable Fonts for *projects, that involve software, that isn't compatible*, yet?

Comment: Hi. If you need to make use of a variable font in software that doesn't support it yet, then I suppose you could use software that does support it, then convert the text to outlines and export in a vector format, or you could export the text in a raster format, and use in whatever software you want.

Comment: yes, indeed. There is even a quite accessible python script "FontTools", that can generate static font subsets from variable fonts.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I've found:

- Adobe apps seem to have good support.
- Inkscape is trying, but buggy.
- Affinity apps don't yet support them.
- There's special interest software, that makes use of VF

There is also this list
https://v-fonts.com/support/